# AWS ECS Environment properties

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have a PHP application that is using the getEnv function to get outside configuration variables for the application.

Similar to how Environment Properties are set in Elastic BeanStalk, how can I pass those environment variables into an ECS EC2 instance?

Also I am use CodePipeline to build a docker image and deploy to ECS to create the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

These variables are defined in the [ECS task definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definitions.html).

Inside the container definition you have the choice of [environment or secret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_environment).

Environment would be used for environment variables that are fine to be passed as plain text, secrets can used either a SecureString in Systems Manager or a secret in Secrets Manager to store the value and only be retrievable during container boot.